# createNavigationDrawer not workin v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, cross-platform, mobile-application

this is the error I got when I run it on the emulator, I have used a functional component for my app, and I also tried it with the component itself and also with a navigation stack

```
17:31
AppLoading threw an unexpected error when loading:
TypeError: interpolate is not a function. (In 'interpolate(this.progress, {
          inputRange: [PROGRESS_EPSILON, 1],
          outputRange: [0, 1]
        })', 'interpolate' is undefined)

 Stack trace:
   node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:148:8 in registerError
   node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:59:8 in errorImpl
   node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:33:4 in console.error
   node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
   node_modules\expo-app-loading\build\AppLoading.js:11:12 in 
startLoadingAppResourcesAsync._catch$argument_0
  node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in 
tryCallOne
  node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in 
setImmediate$argument_0
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:181:14 in 
_callImmediatesPass
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:387:6 in 
__callImmediates
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6 in 
__guard$argument_0
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
  node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4 in 
flushedQueue
  [native code]:null in flushedQueue
  [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your package.json file you have **react-native-reanimated:2.x** version. This version has conflict with react-navigation-drawer:"^2.7.1" version so just remove existing package using `yarn remove react-native-reanimated` and add 1.x version using `yarn add react-native-reanimated@1.0.0`

Comment: I used React navigation 5 instate and that solved my problem but I will try to use your solution too